# Devise - ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/confirm"):

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, devise-confirmable

I am using the 'Confirmable' module for Devise, and doing an '[email-only signup](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Email-only-sign-up)'

However, once the user confirms their email address and adds their password, this is the error I get in my log on Heroku (Cedar Stack):

```
2012-06-20T16:02:37+00:00 app[web.1]: Started PUT "/confirm" for xx.xxx.4x.x2 at 2012-06-20 16:02:37 +0000
2012-06-20T16:02:37+00:00 heroku[router]: POST myapp.herokuapp.com/confirm dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=666ms status=302 bytes=114
2012-06-20T16:02:38+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-06-20T16:02:38+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-06-20T16:02:38+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/confirm" for xx.xxx.4x.x2 at 2012-06-20 16:02:38 +0000
2012-06-20T16:02:38+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/confirm"):
2012-06-20T16:02:38+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `call'
2012-06-20T16:02:38+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:56:in `call'
2012-06-20T16:02:38+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:22:in `call'
2012-06-20T16:02:38+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `call_app'
2012-06-20T16:02:38+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-06-20T16:02:38+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:21:in `call'
2012-06-20T16:02:38+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
2012-06-20T16:02:38+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
2012-06-20T16:02:38+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/lock.rb:15:in `call'
2012-06-20T16:02:38+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.6/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'
2012-06-20T16:02:38+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:62:in `call'
2012-06-20T16:02:38+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-cache-1.2/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:136:in `forward'
2012-06-20T16:02:38+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-cache-1.2/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:245:in `fetch'
2012-06-20T16:02:38+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-cache-1.2/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:185:in `lookup'
2012-06-20T16:02:38+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-cache-1.2/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:51:in `call'
2012-06-20T16:02:38+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-cache-1.2/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:66:in `call!'
2012-06-20T16:02:38+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/engine.rb:479:in `call'
2012-06-20T16:02:38+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.3.1/lib/thin/connection.rb:38:in `receive_data'
2012-06-20T16:02:38+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.3.1/lib/thin/backends/base.rb:61:in `start'
2012-06-20T16:02:38+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.3.1/lib/thin/server.rb:159:in `start'
2012-06-20T16:02:38+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.3.1/lib/thin/connection.rb:78:in `catch'
2012-06-20T16:02:38+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.3.1/lib/thin/controllers/controller.rb:86:in `start'
2012-06-20T16:02:38+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.3.1/lib/thin/runner.rb:185:in `run_command'
2012-06-20T16:02:38+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.3.1/lib/thin/runner.rb:151:in `run!'
2012-06-20T16:02:38+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.3.1/bin/thin:6:in `<top (required)>'
2012-06-20T16:02:38+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bin/thin:19:in `load'
2012-06-20T16:02:38+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bin/thin:19:in `<main>'
2012-06-20T16:02:38+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-06-20T16:02:38+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.3.1/lib/thin/connection.rb:53:in `process'
2012-06-20T16:02:38+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/eventmachine-0.12.10/lib/eventmachine.rb:256:in `run'
2012-06-20T16:02:38+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-06-20T16:02:38+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.3.1/lib/thin/connection.rb:80:in `block in pre_process'
2012-06-20T16:02:38+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/application.rb:220:in `call'
2012-06-20T16:02:38+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.3.1/lib/thin/connection.rb:78:in `pre_process'
2012-06-20T16:02:38+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/eventmachine-0.12.10/lib/eventmachine.rb:256:in `run_machine'
2012-06-20T16:02:38+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
```

The User record gets created successfully, it just doesn't do the routing properly and throws an error.

`Routes.rb`

```
  devise_scope :user do
        put "/confirm" => "confirmations#confirm"  
  end

  devise_for :users, :controllers => { :confirmations => 'confirmations' }
```

`ConfirmationsController.rb`

```
class ConfirmationsController < Devise::ConfirmationsController
  def show
        @categories = Category.all
    self.resource = resource_class.find_by_confirmation_token(params[:confirmation_token])
    super if resource.confirmed? 
  end

  def confirm
    self.resource = resource_class.find_by_confirmation_token(params[resource_name][:confirmation_token])
    if resource.update_attributes(params[resource_name]) && resource.password_match?
      self.resource = resource_class.confirm_by_token(params[resource_name][:confirmation_token])
      set_flash_message :notice, :confirmed
      sign_in_and_redirect(resource_name, resource)
    else
      render :action => "show"
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need that in your routes.rb

```
get "/confirm" => "confirmations#show"
```